# Add fields to report's SQL command

Tags: crystal-reports

I cannot edit the SQL statement in my report.  I know you can't do this directly, but the report is old and I don't know how to add in a field. The SQL statement has these resources hard coded in.

In the select expert it says `@Resource` but I can't find it.

In the database expert I see the links, but it's hard coded in the SQL statement like this 
    OR "Resource"."label"='Skittles' 
and I need to add in two more.  So M&M's and Starburst if you will.

I know this is a simple thing to do but I cannot for the life of me figure it out.  I've been in there all day and just cannot find where it says Resource = Skittles.

The Select Expert - Record says
   ({@Resource} = 'TEST'  I have no idea why.  TEST is not a Resource.  There is no formula for Resource.  In the formula fields again it says 'TEST'

It is grouped buy Resource.  Does that have anything to do with it?

I would really appreciate any help.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Crystal does auto-generate a SQL statement based on your table definitions. I'm guessing that's what you're referring to.

If you want more direct control, you could copy the entire SQL statement you see into a new Command in the Database Expert. Then delete the pre-existing tables.

[image]

From here you'd have complete control over the SQL statement, although you would have to replace any existing fields.

---

If you *don't* want to have to go through and replace every currently-used field in the table, you could always just make an external command that has the new fields you want, plus identifiers, and link based on that.

Comment: I also don't have Add Command under my Connections. I have my connections and create new connection.  In the links, it does not specify the Resource.  How do I add to that?

Comment: Thanks. I ended up creating the whole thing from scratch.  What a pain.  I think what happened was that it was so old and at one point you could hard code the SQL in.  So frustrating.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @CNL No worries then. Don't forget to check this answer as Accepted if it was in fact what you needed.